# Duplicate Value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, stringbuilder, hashcode

I am in big trouble, created a hashMap and inserted two values with same key using 
StringBuilder as a key of map.
Now, while trying to retrieve the data using StringBuilder object is working fine, but in other case its fails to return any value. I have listed three cases in the below given code,

`

```
class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainClass m = new MainClass();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sb");
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("sb");

    Map<StringBuilder, String> map = new HashMap<StringBuilder, String>();
    map.put(sb, "a");
    map.put(sb1, "b");
    System.out.println("----Inside Main method---- mapValue"+map);

    System.out.println("Expected value a, coming also => " + map.get(sb)); //a
    System.out.println("Expected value b, coming also => " + map.get(sb1)); //b
    System.out.println("Expected value a, not coming  => " + map.get("sb")); // why null ?


    m.receiveMap(map, sb, sb1);

}

public void receiveMap(Map<StringBuilder, String> map, StringBuilder refSb,StringBuilder refSb1) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sb");
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("sb");
    System.out.println("----Inside receiveMap method mapValue"+map);
    System.out.println("Expected value a, not coming  => " + map.get(sb)); // why null ?
    System.out.println("Expected value b, not coming  => " + map.get(sb1)); // why null ?

    System.out.println("Expected value a, coming also => " + map.get(refSb)); // o/p - a
    System.out.println("Expected value b, coming also => " + map.get(refSb1)); // o/p -b
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Method `receiveMap`

```
System.out.println("Expected value a, not coming  => " + map.get(sb)); // why null ?
```

Because you are creating new `StringBuilder` sb in the method which having different 
hashcode compare to StringBuilder sb **PSVM**.

StringBuilder doesn't override equals and hashCode

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sb");
  StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("sb");
  Set s = new HashSet();
  s.add(sb);
  s.add(sb1);
  System.out.println(s);
```

Set does not allow duplicate but still it  prints `[sb, sb]` as StringBuilder does not override equals and hashcode method.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, one `StringBuilder` instance is NOT equal to another (hence they will get different hashcodes, and are handled as separate entities) . Just because 2 `StringBuilder` (or any Objects) have same value, that doesn't mean that they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `String`, `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode`, and therefore is uses the default implementation of `Object` class. Therefore `sb.equals(sb1)` is false, even though they contain the same characters.

I suggest you use a `String` instead of `StringBuilder` as the key to your Map.

Answer (score 0):

You have created different instances of `StringBuilder`, which are not same.

You yourself have tested out almost all scenarios, confusion should have been clear.

`StringBuilder` does not overrride `hashCode()` and `equals()` method, which `HashMap` requires to work properly.

> System.out.println("Expected value a, not coming  => " +
>   map.get("sb")); // why

new `StringBuilder object` has been created and passed.

```
> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sb");
>         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("sb");
>         System.out.println("----Inside receiveMap method mapValue" + map);
>         System.out.println("Expected value a, not coming  => " + map.get(sb)); // why
>         System.out.println("Expected value b, not coming  => " + map.get(sb1)); // why
```

here also new objects `sb1` and `sb` have been created which are not equal to previously created, though content is same, but references are different.

> Also try changing Map to
>
> ```
> Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
> ```
>
> and use `.toString()` method, you will observe different behaviour,
>   because `String` class overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing objects which are not in Map so it returns null.Every time you pass correct object,you are getting value.

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuilder it will never work as one instance is NOT equal to another StringBuilder instance

Correct your code to something like this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(sb.toString(), "a");
        map.put(sb1.toString(), "b");
```

but as this is a map representation if the sb.toString() and sb1.toString() are equal like in your example the value will be overridden

So the output with the corrections to your code is

```
----Inside Main method---- mapValue{sb=b}
Expected value a, coming also => b
Expected value b, coming also => b
Expected value a, not coming  => b
----Inside receiveMap method mapValue{sb=b}
Expected value a, not coming  => b
Expected value b, not coming  => b
Expected value a, coming also => b
Expected value b, coming also => b
```